# Resize Flash with Javascript?

Tags: javascript, flash, internet-explorer

I'm wondering if its possible to resize flash with javascript. I can't change any code in the flash object alone all I have is html, javascript and php to work with.

Heres what I've found so far:

```
    var changeMe = document.getElementById("content_embed");
  changeMe.height = yy;
  changeMe.width = xx;
  if (navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf("safari")!=-1) {
    var changemeObject = document.getElementById("content_object");
    changeMeObject.height = yy;
    changeMeObject.width = xx;
  }
}
```

Content Embed is the embed tag and content object is the object tag in the flash. This works in chrome (and probably firefox) but not ie.
In internet explorer I get the error: `Unable to set value of the property 'height': object is null or undefined`

 Here is the example page I have been using:http://futuregamespc.com/behind/Popup/
Can anyone help? Thanks guys, you're what makes this site awesome.

Comment: try using jquery to abstract away all that browser specific code you have there.

Comment: http://futuregamespc.com/behind/Popup/index2.html does that and it doesn't work in chrome or internet explorer and odly enough it doesn't return any error, just doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is possible.

But, please use [swfobject](http://code.google.com/p/swfobject/) whenever you display flash in your website.

> Its a lightweight JavaScript library
>   that allows you to integrate swf in a
>   cross browser friendly way to your
>   website.

The below given is a sample of the call to swfobject

```
var flashvars = {};
var params = {};
var attributes = {};
var width="300";
var height="120";

swfobject.embedSWF("myContent.swf", "myContent", width, height, "9.0.0","expressInstall.swf", flashvars, params, attributes);
```

As you can see, `height` and `width` are passed are parameters.
[Read swfobject documentation](http://code.google.com/p/swfobject/wiki/documentation) for more details.

Update: Here is [another good write up on using swfobject](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flashplayer/articles/swfobject.html) on the Adobe site itself.

Comment: i'm not sure this meets the dynamic criteria the op is looking for.  he wants to resize the swf after it has been loaded into the dom.  using this advice he'd have to destroy and recreate the object, which could be an issue if it needs to remain in the same place across resizes

Comment: thanks this is just what i was looking for. I can use it for all swf files without much changing. I wanted a solution that would save the state of the flash file and this works perfectly.